# How to move a logical volume from one disk to another?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

My partitions right now are as follows:

```
sda                     8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    0 223.1G  0 part 
  ├─vg-lv1              254:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg-lv2              254:1    0   3.7T  0 lvm  /home
sdb                     8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   3.7T  0 part 
  └─vg-lv2              254:1    0   3.7T  0 lvm  /home
```

Basically, I am trying to move `vg-lv2` from `sda2` to `sdb1`. How do I do this?

In the end I want my partitions to look something like this:

```
sda                     8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    0 223.1G  0 part 
  └─vg-lv1              254:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
sdb                     8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   3.7T  0 part 
  └─vg-lv2              254:1    0   3.7T  0 lvm  /home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pvmove -n lv1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1
```

moves the LVM LV `/dev/vg1/lv1` to `/dev/sdb1`.